# How to put logo at the top (header side) of title page in beamer (theme warsaw)?

Tags: beamer, themes

I want to put 2 logos at the header of title page as illustrated in figure, any idea please?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please check the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2pc,left]{}
 \colorbox{green}{\hbox to 5pc{\vbox to 2pc{}}}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2pc,right]{}
 \colorbox{red}{\hbox to 5pc{\vbox to 2pc{}}}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here you can change `\colorbox{green}{\hbox to 5pc{\vbox to 2pc{}}}` and `\colorbox{red}{\hbox to 5pc{\vbox to 2pc{}}}` with `\includegraphics{...}`. Also you can change the height by changing `ht=2pc`.